# Java Anagram - Simple Challenge

Tags: java, anagram

Hello Stack Overflow Community. I developed a simple Java program to detect whether or not a word entered by the user is an Anagram. I do not receive the expected output based on the boolean value. Any ideas or suggestions are appreciated.

Note: This code does not include any methods or class functions that would make this a rather simple solution. Please work with the code below. Thank you!

```
import javax.swing.*;

public class Anagram 
{
public static String word = " ";
public static boolean match = false;

public static void main(String[] args)
{   
    //Prompt the User for a Word
    word = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Please Enter A Word");

    //Break the Word into an Array
    String[] anagram = new String[word.length()];

    for(int i = 0; i < word.length(); i++)
    {
        anagram[i] = Character.toString(word.charAt(i));
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, anagram[i]);
    }

    //Create a duplicate Array 
    String[] anagram2 = new String[word.length()];

    for(int i = word.length() - 1; i >= 0; i--)
    {
        anagram2[i] = anagram[i];
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, anagram2[i]);
    }

    //Do a search on each letter
    for (int i = 0; i < anagram.length && i < anagram2.length; i++)
    {
        if(anagram.length == anagram2.length)
        {   
            if(anagram[i].toLowerCase() == anagram2[i].toLowerCase())
            {
                match = true;
            }
            else
            {
                match = false;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "There is a mismatch");
            match = false;
        }
    }

    //Prompt the user with the result
    if(match == true)
    {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Your Word is a Anagram!");
    }
    else if(match == false)
    {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Your Word is NOT a Anagram!");
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Are you sure you don't mean palindrome?

Comment: Possible duplicate [How do I compare strings in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/513832/how-do-i-compare-strings-in-java)

Comment: first be clear on what an anagram is. your length check is false: add, dad and dd a are anagrams, even though dd a doesn't have the same length as add and dad

Comment: just a few questions: what do you expect? what is your input? why don't you use methods?

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: How to create a [mcve]. Use the "edit" link to improve your *question* - do not add more information via comments. Thanks!

Comment: Pardon the inconvenience everyone, this exercise was meant to be a palindrome.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you mean palindrome:

Your code doesn't actually reverse the String.

```
for(int i = word.length() - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
    anagram2[i] = anagram[i];
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, anagram2[i]);
}
```

This copies anagram into anagram2 without reversing it - it does go through it from back to front, but the result will be the same.

You need to do something like

```
for (int i = 0; i < word.length(); i++) {
    anagram2[word.length() - i - 1] = anagram[i];
}
```

However, there really is no need to create the anagram and anagram2 arrays in the first place, you can just iterate through the String's data itself using charAt.

```
boolean match = true;
for (int i = 0; i < word.length(); i++) {
    if (word.charAt(i) != word.charAt(word.length() - i - 1)) {
        match = false;
        break;
    }
}
```

Side note, you shouldn't declare `word` and `match` as static variables, keeping them local in `main()` will do.